# Carbon get years between specified start year and current year

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

Is there anyway to get the years between a start year and current year in an array, if possible with Carbon?

So this year the array would be:

```
[2014,2015,2016]
```

And next year 2017 will be included:

```
[2014,2015,2016,2017]
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Solution:

```
$years = range(Carbon::now()->year, 2014)
```