# laravel Carbon calculate age at death (not till now)

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

get age till now() can use the code below

```
// Accessor for Age.
public function getAgeAttribute()
{
    return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['birth_date'])->age;
}
```

but what about if the person is dead ?

in the database [death_date] field stored null or yyyy-mm-dd

so how to calculate the age between birth date ~ death date

```
// Accessor for Age.
public function getAgeAttribute()
{
    if (!is_null($this->attributes['death_date']))
    {
        // how to calculate death_date - birth_date = realAge
        return $realAge;
    }

    return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['birth_date'])->age;
}
```

just in case someone view this post, here is my answer

```
// Accessor for Age.
public function getAgeAttribute()
{
    // return is_null($this->attributes['death_date'])
    //     ? Carbon::parse($this->attributes['birth_date'])->age
    //     : Carbon::parse($this->attributes['birth_date'])->diff(Carbon::parse($this->attributes['death_date']))->format('%y');

    // oh, Carbon will auto convert NULL to now(), so no need the upper code
    return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['birth_date'])->diff(Carbon::parse($this->attributes['death_date']))->format('%y');
}
```

Comment: check this post
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007075/carbon-get-years-between-specified-start-year-and-current-year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007075/carbon-get-years-between-specified-start-year-and-current-year)

Comment: @ali and Oscar A Garcia and climon use the same calculation, but i  prefer ali answer, thankyou guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can solve it as the following:

```
public function getAgeAttribute()
 {
 if (!is_null($this->attributes['death_date']))
 {
     $realAge = Carbon::parse($this->attributes['death_date'])->diff(Carbon::parse($this->attributes['birth_date']))->format('%y');
      return $realAge
  }

 return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['birth_date'])->age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$birth_date = Carbon::parse($this->attributes['birth_date']);
$death_date = Carbon::parse($this->attributes['death_date']);

echo $birth_date->diffInYears($death_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking for the age in years, try this:

```
$birth = new Carbon($this->attributes['birth_date']);
$death = new Carbon($this->attributes['death_date']);

$age = $birth->diffInYears($death); // Returns Integer
```